# How to send buffer image data from node js to ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am practicing of uploading and fetching images from database using node js. The uploading part went very well, but fetching part is giving some problems, the code for fetching images is `app.get('/images', async (req, res) => { const img = await image(image is the model with type of buffer).find({}); res.render('image', { img }) }`. The ejs template part is `<% img.forEach(i => { <img src="data:img/png;base64,<%= i.avatar(avatar is property on the image model) %>"> }`.
Can someone tell how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

You should probably map the `avatar` buffer to a `base64`-encoded string and pass that to the ejs-template:

```
app.get('/images', async (req, res) => {
    const img = await image().find({});
    img.avatar = Buffer.from(img.avatar).toString('base64');
    res.render('image', {img});
});
```